# Processing user input in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read user input on an infinite loop in a C program. The function that does this is as below.

```
void processUserInput(unsigned int io, char* cmd, char* buffer){

   char* usrInput;

   int rbytes;
   if ((rbytes = read(io, buffer, 256)) < 0) {
      perror("Read error: ");
      exit(-1);
   }
   buffer[rbytes-1] = 0;

   usrInput = (char*) calloc(256, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(usrInput, buffer);

   cmd = strtok(usrInput, " ");
}
```

In my main, this is what I do.

```
char buffer[256];
char* cmd = NULL;
processUserInput(STDIN_FILENO, cmd, buffer);

if(strcasecmp(cmd, "quit") == 0){

   breakTrigger = 1;

}
memset(buffer, 0, 256);
```

The code gives a `segmentation fault` the moment I enter an input on STDIN.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `read` to get user input? You should use `getline` or `fgets(..., ..., stdin)`.

Comment: Search for and read about *pass by value* and *pass by reference* and how to use *pass by reference* in C.

Comment: why do you need the global buffer variable? since you are allocating memory to userinput to hold the value for the input it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the parameter type of cmd.  In processUserInput, cmd is a pointer to a char (string), so, you can change what cmd points to, but cmd will not be changed when method returns.  You should either call processUserInput with &cmd, and within processUserInput do *cmd = strtok(...), or better yet, just have processUserInput return cmd.

```
char* processUserInput(unsigned int io, char* buffer){

   char* usrInput;

   int rbytes;
   if ((rbytes = read(io, buffer, 256)) < 0) {
      perror("Read error: ");
      exit(-1);
   }
   buffer[rbytes-1] = 0;

   usrInput = (char*) calloc(256, sizeof(char));
   strcpy(usrInput, buffer);

   return strtok(usrInput, " ");
}

char buffer[256];
char* cmd = processUserInput(STDIN_FILENO, buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is to write

```
cmd = strtok(usrInput, " ");
```

This is not *storing* the content of the returned pointer *into* `cmd`. Therefore, in `main()`, your `cmd` remains `NULL`. Later, the call to `strcasecmp()` creates UB because of `NULL` pointer.

You need to

1. Allocate memory to `cmd` in `main()`, before passing that to `processUserInput()`.
2. Check for non-null return of `strtok()`
3. `strcpy()` the returned token to `cmd`.

Also, as a side-note, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).